# Is it possible to use a non Hunspell dictionary in TeXstudio?

Tags: texstudio, dictionaries

Is it possible to use a non Hunspell dictionary in TeXstudio?

I would like to use the dictionary on this website (http://www.uzei.eus/hobelex/) but the authors decided not to use the Hunspell engine for accuracy reasons. Is it possible to install it? Or does TeXstudio not support other formats?

Comment: @Raaja I have checked that thread and they all suggest solutions for hunspell dictionaries. The dictionary I want to use has no .dic or .aff files.

Comment: I am sorry, since I did not had the competence in that regime. I have removed the comment.